# How navigate from one page to another?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Currently I am working on a xaml page with several buttons that are going to link to other xaml pages, but I cannot figure out how to navigate from one xaml page to another. This is what I currently have.

```
Private Sub GoTools(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    MainFrame.Navigate(New Uri("Tools.xaml"))
End Sub
```

This is what I have seen on a lot of websites so far but this does not work, how should I change this so that when I click a Tools button it brings me to the Tools page?
(Quotes have been changed)

When I run the program and click the button I get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

Comment: That can't even compile.  Look at your quotes:  `“Tools.xaml”`  Now look at an actual quote that is valid syntactically: `"` You've copied that from some website that has converted quotes into the fancy versions where the first set has a blob on the bottom and the second set has a blob on the top.  Fix that and come back and tell us in an [edit] what happened.

Comment: You need to pass a valid URI to the `Uri` constructor - you can use the second parameter to specify that you are using a relative URI, otherwise the default is `UriKind.Absolute` - see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492(v=vs.110).aspx (look at the Remarks section)

Comment: Remarkable how the question changes when you include error messages :/

Comment: Charleh, I tried using the example from the website you gave but I still get the same error, do you think it is a problem with my Tools.xaml address?

Answer (score 0):

How about you do it this way:

```
Private Sub GoTools(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
  MainFrame.Navigate(New Tool)
End Sub
```

I am not familiar with VB, but you have to create an instance of your Tool page. In case you already have one just navigate to it.

Comment: Also, the Tools object must inherit from Page

Comment: I assume it does when he calls it page.